# Python : How to compare two csv files and print out the matching strings in a new file

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to compare two csv files, and print out the matching strings to a third file. In my case i have a file1 naming raw_data.csv which contains 3 columns as name_id's, reference_id and compound_name. File2 naming new_data.csv has only one column as compound_name. I would like to match data in column compound_name from both files, and print out the name_id's and reference_id's of similar compound_name to new file  final.csv.

File1 - raw_data.csv

```
name_id         reference_id     compound_name
IVRD345         456TTRY          Citrulline_malate
IVRD456         657TRDF          Succinic_acid
IVRD624         473YRHW          Glutamic_acid
```

File2 - new_data.csv

```
compound_name
calcium
glutamic_acid
citric_acid
```

Thank you

Comment: [pandas merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) will be helpful here

Comment: i tried by editing a code i found on github  -   but im very new to python, so i failed badly                                               
                                                                                                                     
import csv
file_list = ['file1.csv', 'file2.csv']

f1 = open(file_list[0], 'r').readlines()
f2 = open(file_list[1], 'r').readlines()

fName = open('final.csv', 'a')
for _ in range(2):
    for row in f1:
        if row in f2:
            fName.write(row)
    f1, f2 = f2, f1

Comment: If you are using a shell with grep available, `grep -Ff new_data.csv raw_data.csv` probably gets what you need.

Comment: i tried it but some data i'm missing. so wanted to try in python

Comment: @dexter_danny, please select an answer if one of the two solutions below are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code:

```
import pandas as pd
df1=pd.read_csv('raw_data.csv')
df2=pd.read_csv('new_data.csv')
df_final=pd.merge(df1,df2,on=['compound_name'])
df_final.to_csv('final.csv',columns=['name_id','reference_id'])
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I'd load both into pandas and then compare where they're duplicated like so:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv('raw_data.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('new_data.csv')
df_all = pd.concat([df1,df2])
df_all["duplicate"] = df_all.duplicated(keep='first',subset=['compound_name'])
```

You can then:

```
for index, row in df_all.iterrows():
   if row['duplicate']:
      print("Name ID: {} and Reference ID: {}".format(row['name_id'],row['reference_id']))
```